# I cannot understand this sentence containing "additional to"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I just read the following sentence:

> The square brackets in character class expressions are additional to
> the square brackets delimiting a collection.

From the context following it, this should mean that we can have `[]` inside character class expressions, and they will not be treated as the original meaning of `[]`. Instead, they are treated as delimiting characters. But from the quoted sentence I cannot get this conclusion. Can anyone help me understand it step by step?

This is the source I'm reading: (click to open in another page if it's too small)

[image]

Comment: Without context, the quoted sentence does not have that meaning. It vaguely means there are two sets of square brackets. What makes the meaning clear is the rest of the context. That sentence alone does not have that clear meaning.

Comment: @gotube Then I will make a suggestion for improving the docs. Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: I didn't say the docs aren't good. They explain the concept clearly enough in the context. Everything is understood in terms of its context, and in this case, it includes the rest of the paragraph. THAT SAID, it wouldn't hurt if it read something like this instead: *The square brackets in character class expressions **operate independently** to the square brackets delimiting a collection.*

Comment: Please do not include images of text. They hinder searchability and accessibility. See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/91457 and https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/screenshots-in-questions-what-should-we-do-to-discourage-such-behavior/5365#5365

Comment: Since this is a question about the syntax of a regular expression engine, I vote that it be moved to a more appropriate site such as Computer Science, Stack Overflow or Software Engineering. Also, as David Siegel says, can we please have a proper link to the source of your quote and a note of which particular engine we are talking about. There tend to be minor differences between different implimentations